# Is it possible to define a custom cast on an object to become the result of a method call?

Tags: c++, casting, c++17

Is it possible to define a custom cast on an object so that the objects casts to the result of a method call?

```
class Foo {
  public:
    ...
    int method() { return 3; }
};

Foo foo;
int bar = foo + 7; // 10
```

Comment: Are you looking for [cast operators](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cast_operator)?

Comment: What's wrong with `foo.method() + 7`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Agh. I was overthinking it.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class Foo {
    public:
    Foo() { _data = 3; }
    int method() { return _data; }
    operator int() {
        return method();
    }
    int _data;
};

int main()
{
  Foo foo;
  int bar = foo + 7;
  std::cout << bar << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could provide a **conversion function** as shown below:

##### Method 1

Directly return an `int` without using `method` inside the conversion function.

```
class Foo {
  public:
    //conversion function
    operator int()
    {
        return 3;
    }
};

Foo foo;
int bar = foo + 7; // bar is initialized with 10

int main()
{
    std::cout<<bar;//prints 10
    return 0;
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/49Wjasj9s)

Or

##### Method 2

Use `method` to return an `int` from inside the conversion function.

```
class Foo {
  public:
    
    int method() { return 3; }
    
    operator int()
    {
        return method();
    }
};

Foo foo;
int bar = foo + 7; // 10

int main()
{
    std::cout<<bar;//prints 10
    return 0;
}
```